# How do I fetch a stored postgres function from php

Tags: php, postgresql, function

Just a little confused here...

I have a function in postgres, and when I'm at the pg prompt, I just do:

```
SELECT zp('zc',10,20,90);
FETCH ALL FROM zc;
```

I'm wondering how to do this from php?

I thought I could just do:

```
$q = pg_query("SELECT zp('zc',10,20,90)");
```

But, how do I "fetch" from that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the FETCH-query to the database:

```
$result = pg_query("FETCH ALL FROM zc;");
```

You can now use a while-loop to fetch all the results in $result or just just pg_fetch_all() to fetch in PHP.

Comment: I see... So, I put in *both* queries?  First, the function call, and then the fetch?

Comment: Looks like your function returns a cursor, so you need two queries to receive the result.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I appreciate the guidance and the ability to dumb things down for a newb.  :)